# How set properties on relationships in NEO4J API?

Tags: java, api, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm using the `Neo4J API`. I created the following relationship between two nodes:

```
node1.createRelationshipTo(graphDb.getNodeById(idNode2), new RelationshipType() {
    @Override
    public String name() {
        return "CONECTED";
    }
});
```

How do I set a property for this relationship?

Comment: For relationship-types it is easier to use `DynamicRelationshipType.withName("CONNECTED")` or `enum RelTypes implements RelationshipType { CONNECTED }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That call you're doing there returns a `Relationship` object.  You can see the javadocs for that [here](http://neo4j.com/api_docs/2.0.3/org/neo4j/graphdb/Relationship.html).

`Relationship` objects and `Node` objects both implement [`PropertyContainer`](http://neo4j.com/api_docs/2.0.3/org/neo4j/graphdb/PropertyContainer.html).   So you just use the `setProperty()` method that's implemented from PropertyContainer in the Relationship class.

```
Relationship r = node1.createRelationshipTo(graphDb.getNodeById(idNode2), new RelationshipType() {
    @Override
    public String name() {
        return "CONECTED";
    }
});

r.setProperty("PropertyName", "PropertyValue");
```